Network printer Canon iR2930
I am trying to access a network printer (Canon iR2930) from my terminal. I have followed several guides but nothing really worked. Examples are:
https://itsubuntu.com/how-to-install-canon-printer-driver-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts/
as well as the guide that comes with the driver downloaded from Canon's website.
Talking with the IT guy of my department, I should need to insert an username and password somewhere, but no queries about such data appear anywhere. He says that on Windows this request is automatic. But since I don't want to give up, I hope you guys can give me a hand.
Please let me know if you need more information and I will update this post accordingly.
EDIT:
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Below, I will describe a couple of methods I used:
Ubuntu way

I opened the standard printer manager in Ubuntu (the one in the settings)
I added a new printer by entering its IP-address.
I selected the proper one (called iR2925-2039-UFR-II)-
I tried to print the a test page with no success.

Canon driver

I downloaded the drivers from the following address: Canon
imageRUNNER 2930i.
Specifically, I first download the .tar.gz packet, from which I used the install.sh file, then I also installed it via the .deb package.
I followed the instructions in Canon Manual.
In particular, I used # cnsetuputil2 to open the Canon Printer Setup Utility. I selected the printer I am interested in (Canon iR 2925/2930 UFR II), I inserted the printer address.
I tried to print a test page, but it did not work.

Windows printer via SAMBA
Inspired by the fact that the IT told me that he had no problem on Windows, I tried the "windows printer via SAMBA" option when selecting a new printer.

I inserted the printer address.
I tried to enter my printer username and password as well not entering them
When prompted for the driver, I selected the model of the printer and selected the suggested option or, on a different occasion, the UFR II option.
I clicked on next till the end since I wasn't interested in the other options.
I tried to print a test page, but, again, no result.
This time, however, it first gave me the error message
Unable to connect to CIFS host: NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND. Will retry in 60 seconds.... Then, I got Unable to connect to CIFS host after (tried 3 times)

Reading around, I also found this other link, suggesting to use the hostname instead of the IP-address when registering the printer via SAMBA.
So I did, but there was no difference.
As a final notice, only this last option gave me the possibility of inserting a username and password. There was no way in the other methods.
